# How to 'fix' the SML/NJ interactive system to use Arrow Keys

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm having some trouble using SML/NJ interactive system, namely, that when I try to use my arrow keys (either left or right to make a correction in the expression I've typed, up to repeat the last expression), my Terminal prints codes. (e.g. `^[[A` for up`^[[D` for left, etc.).  While I can still use the system, it makes it very tedious.

I've looked around in Control.Compiler, is there something I'm missing?  For whatever its worth, I'm using the Mac Terminal.

Thanks ^_^

Comment: what a great language however the implementation of its interpretor is not user friendly at all. I cant find an equivalent of ipython for smlj which is unfortunate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this.  You can use socat to add readline support to many things:

```
socat READLINE EXEC:sml
```

I just realized you're on OS X.  socat does seem to be available for OS X, although I have not tested it (this does work on Linux).

Comment: on my Linux, I use "rlwrap" to do the same thing: http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/

Comment: THANK YOU ^_^  Oh that feels so much better (though it took a fair bit of work getting socat up and working.  The next box is a Linux).

Answer (score 56):

Another option is [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap).

```
rlwrap sml
```

Comment: If you have [macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php), you can install `rlwrap` by running `sudo port install rlwrap`.  Then add `alias sml='rlwrap /usr/local/smlnj/bin/sml'` to a new line on your `~/.bash_profile` file.

Comment: I didn't know about rlwrap (or abusing socat as mentioned above) until I found this answer! Thanks!

Comment: Also works with homebrew: brew install rlwrap. You don't even need to change your bash_profile.

Comment: If you are using the `alias sml=path` suggested by @justspamjustin, you can find the `path` of your `sml` command by running `which sml`