# Standard ML repeat last command, left arrow?

Tags: functional-programming, interpreter, sml, ml, ledit

I am learning standard ML using its interpreter. Sometimes I make typo and just want to repeat the previous command like in Linux shell. However, up arrow will end up with printing special characters on the screen. Sometimes I want to go back left to correct something, left arrow also results in printing special characters.

Does anybody know what is the correct way to do them?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911861/how-to-fix-the-sml-nj-interactive-system-to-use-arrow-keys

Comment: Excellent! How come I didn't find that at google... Thanks a lot for pointing out, that is awesome!

Answer (score 9):

I use Moscow ML, but I figure the answer will apply to whichever version you use:

You can achieve what you want by using [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/).

I have the following alias set in my `.zshrc`, which handles it automatically:

```
alias mosml="rlwrap mosml"
```

(Substitute `mosml` for the name of your SML interpreter.)

Answer (score 6):

Consider using the program ledit. It allows you to use the arrow keys to visit previous commands.

Example:

```
ledit mosml
```

Comment: this is beautiful and works for smlnj and others too - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing any serious SML hacking I strongly suggest you use a development environment that allows you to interact with the SML top level environment.

I use Emacs with the [SML mode](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~monnier/elisp/). The beauty here is that in the top window you can code functions and save them to a file. You can then send them to the lower window that holds the Inferior-SML process for compilation. Also the Inferior-SML process has by default a command history.